# My fluid inflow doesn't stop even after animating it keyframes (useflow) to stop

Tags: animation, keyframes, fluid-simulation

I have been learning blender for 2 months now, I get stock at this point where I am finding it very difficult to animate a running fluid from the flow into the effector
Pls can someone explain how to stop fluid, I have watch countless of videos but it seems am not getting what is going on

Comment: pls provide your blend file so we can check it out what you did wrong. thx.

Comment: Please reduce your case to the simplest demonstration of your problem, and illustrate it, with a clear, straightforward description. You can share that on https://blend-exchange.com/ .  We can't help without enough to go on.